# Firestore query takes a too long time to get the value of only one field

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

. Hi, community.

I have a question/issue about **firestore** query from Firebase.

I have a collection of around 18000 documents. I would like to get the value of a single same field of some of these documents. I use the **python** firestore_v1 library from google-cloud-python client. So, for example with list_edges.length = 250:

```
[db_firestore.document(f"edges/{edge['id']}").get({"distance"}).to_dict()["distance"] for edge in list_edges]
```

it takes like 30+ seconds to be evaluated, meanwhile with the equal collection on MongoDB it takes not more than 3 seconds doing this and loading the whole object, not only a one field:

```
list(db_mongo["edges"].find({"city_id":{"$eq":city_id},"id": {"$in": [edge_id for edge in list_edges]}}))
```

...having said that, I thought the solution could be separate the large collection by city_id, so I create a new collection and copy the corresponded documents inside, so now the query looks like:

```
[db_firestore.document(f"edges/7/edges/{edge['id']}").get({"distance"}).to_dict()["distance"] for edge in list_edges]
```

where 7 is a city_id.

However, it takes the same time. So, maybe the issue is around the .get() method, but I could not find any optimized solution for my case.

Could you help me with this? Thanks!

---

**EDITED**

I've got the answer from firestore support. The problem is that I make 250 requests doing .get() for each document separately. The idea is to get all the data I want in only one request, so I need to modify the query.

Let's assume I have the next DB:

edges collection with multiples edge_id documents. For each new request, I use a new generated list of edges I need to catch.

In MongoDB, I can do it with the **$in** operator (having edge_id inside the document), but in firestore, the 'in' operator [only accepts up to 10 equality](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).

So, I need to find out another way to do this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The good news is that the time it takes seems to solely depend on `list_edges.length = 250`, and not on the size of the collection, which is in line with Firestore's main performance guarantee: the time an operation takes depends on the size of the result set, not on the size of the collection you query. Unfortunately I have no idea if the performance you see is expected from the Firestore Python SDK, nor what would cause it if it isn't (hence leaving only a comment, and no answer).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your comment. I have updated the question, now is more like the query constructor question, not the library performance issue. Maybe you have some ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase recently added support for a limited `in` operation. See:

- The [blog post announcing the feature](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html).
- The documentation on [`in` and `array-contains-any` queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).

From the latter:

> ```
> cities_ref = db.collection(u'cities')
>
> query = cities_ref.where(u'country', u'in', [u'USA', u'Japan'])
> ```

A few caveats though:

- You can have at most 10 values in the `in` clause, and you can have only on `in` (or `array-contains-any`) clause in query.
- I am not sure if you can use this operator to select by ID.

Comment: In my case, I have an array with more than 10 values.
And select by ID is not a problem as I can repeat it as one of the document fields.

Comment: That means you'll need to do this for each batch of 10 IDs. If the number of requests is the bottle neck, this may make it up to 10x faster.